# Is there a way to call a value from a different scene and script from unity without making that script run?

Tags: c#, sql, unity-game-engine

This code should call update the info in the table using the inputted username

[image: This code should call update the info in the table using the inputted username]

This calls the script which is currently on an empty object in the hierarchy

[image: This calls the script which is currently on an empty object in the hierarchy]

This is saved on a different scene and script on unity

[image: This is saved on a different scene and script on unity]

However, if I run the code and try to implement it this way, an error occurs as I have functions in the awake and start which only works for the scene it originally was in.

Comment: please don't post images of code see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: and, completely unrelated to your issue, be informed about SQL injection: having an unchecked variable "userinput" (which, I guess, is the input from the user), used directly in the query, could be disastrous. https://xkcd.com/327/.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, but before moving on to those, a few notes about designing your classes especially with regards to things you intend to use for DB updates.

Having such features unchecked is a Really Bad Idea™ !
Please make sure you do not publish such code unless you're absolutely certain it can ever get in the wrong hands (which it usually can even if not intended).


So how to get those references? Since you need a monobehaviour to get the input and i'm presuming you want to keep this contained on the same object/script i would recommend using the Singleton pattern, the script would have a static member of it's own type that it sets in Awake (and to avoid a second instance overriding it should nullcheck the setting and destroy itself if one already exists).

```
public LoginDB : MonoBehaviour
{
  public static LoginDB Instance;

  private void Awake()
  {
    if ( Instance == null ) // Don't use equals for monobehaviours, google for why
      Instance = this;
    else
      Destroy(gameObject);
  }
}
```

Then you can use that in the calling class to get the reference like so:

```
var loginDB = LoginDB.Instance;
string userName = loginDB.userInput; // for example
```

To ensure fully reliable execution you must obviously ensure an instance of the object exists prior to calling that, or you could use a Coroutine to do what's commonly referred to a Lazy Initialize, where you start a Coroutine when initializing and have it wait for the instance ref to not be null before allowing calls to it.

Singletons are at times frowned upon in some circles but they are quite appropriate in environments where you do not get to dictate the architecture such as when using third party game engines. Make judicious use of them, ie only when the use case is something that only one instance should ever be in existence (presuming your database accessing application does not do split screen multiplayer..)